# Horsepower achieved with multiple motors

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, electronics

**Scenario**

I'm planning to build an electric motor for fun (not for any practical purpose). I recently purchased a shapeoko CNC mill kit and intend to manufacture most of the parts housing, stator etc. I'm currently in the planning stage and would like to plan/build this intelligently vs trial and error.

**Goals**
move 200lb (including the motors) at about 5-10mph (faster end of that if possible)

**Questions**

1. How do you calculate the torque/hp that a motor will produce?
2. If I put 4 smaller motors (instead of 1 powering the entire drive train) on the job can each produce less torque/hp and still achieve my goals?

I understand the basics of building an electric brushless motor, I'm more interested on how to plan a motor for a specific output.

## EDIT

After some more research it seems that `1 HP = 745.699872 watts`

[image]

so to move 200lb at 5 mph

- I need a `0.0019511579888525 horsepower` motor.
- I need to provide `1.4549782617235 watts` to the motor.

AND to move 200lb at 10mph

- I need a `0.01560926391082 horsepower` motor.
- I need to provide `11.639826093788 watts` to the motor.

I still need to figure out how **Question 2** factors into my calculations.

Comment: Are you moving horizontally opposing friction, or vertically opposing gravity, or both? Note that power is $W=F\cdot V$ without any exponents as stated in the question. I calculate about 4000 Watts, which makes more sense given the requirements.

Comment: horizontally opposing friction, where did my math go wrong? should i not calculate `W` off of horsepower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the weight is $F$ in pounds, the coefficient of friction $\mu$ and the speed of $v$ in mph then the power $W$ required to maintain this motion in Watts is

$$ W  \approx 2.0 \mu \cdot F \cdot v $$

The coefficient of $2.0$ comes from the conversion into metric units. To move 200 lbs at 10 mph with a coefficient of friction of $\mu=0.4$ is

$$ W \approx 2.0 (0.4) (200\; {\rm lbf}) (10\; {\rm mph}) = 1600 \; {\rm Watt} = 2.15 \;{\rm hp} $$

This power comes from $W=I\,V$ where $I$ is current and $V$ is voltage, without losses or a fraction of this product with losses. I guess you can get the details from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor). An online calculator is also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APMonitor#Direct_current_.28DC.29_motor).

Answer (score 0):

> Goals move 200lb at 10mph.

The power required to keep a speed depends on the coefficient of friction and coefficient of drag. Both heavily depends on the shape of the object, the terrain on which the object moves, the types of tires used, the transmission used and so on. The question is not well posed.

But as an example the typical 250W e-bike usually reach about 25KM/h with the weight and the drag of a person. Most of the energy will be lost to air resistance in this case. The 1600W from the other answer seems **a bit** too much.

> If I put 4 smaller motors (instead of 1 powering the entire drive
>   train) on the job can each produce less torque/hp and still achieve my
>   goals?

In general, yes. The motors should produce 1/4 of the torque ad consequently 1/4 the the power in the same speed range.